# Oracle ORDER BY Complex Query Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

We have a complex SQL query encompassing multiple views, partitions, control flow etc. On the final output we expect to be able to return the Gross Cost and Line cost on the same row; both of these columns have been previously partitioned in the underlying views which successfully prevents duplications. Below is an example:

```
PO Number    Gross Cost    Line #    Line Cost    Inv #    Inv Cost
      10          10000         1        10000        1        2000
      10                        1                     2        3000
      10                        1                     3        5000
```

Instead, we get:

```
PO Number    Gross Cost    Line #    Line Cost    Inv #    Inv Cost
      10          10000         1                     1        2000
      10                        1                     2        3000
      10                        1        10000        3        5000
```

Or, with an ORDER BY table.gross_cost, table.line_cost, we get:

```
PO Number    Gross Cost    Line #    Line Cost    Inv #    Inv Cost
      10          10000         1                     1        2000
      10                        1         10000       2        3000
      10                        1                     3        5000
```

Vice-versa with the ORDER BY switched around to table.line_cost, table.gross_cost, we get:

```
PO Number    Gross Cost    Line #    Line Cost    Inv #    Inv Cost
      10                        1        10000        1        2000
      10          10000         1                     2        3000
      10                        1                     3        5000
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Is there any way we can achieve the first table example through an ORDER BY clause, or do we have to go down a GROUP BY route? I have even attempted to create an Order column through a CASE WHEN statement, but this also did not work.

Comment: `ORDER BY` only reorders complete rows. No matter of reordering a complete row will move one value from row 2 up to row 1 without moving _all_ values from row 2 to row 1. Maybe you can solve your actual problem using the `LAG()` and/or `LEAD()` window functions: `select po_number, gross_cost, lead(line_cost) over (partition by po_number order by inv), inv, inv_cost from my_view` .

Comment: Cheers for the insight into LEAD and LAG functions, I will definitely be using them in the future. For now, I managed to create an Order By clause within one of the inner views and a further Order By on the outer view which is working.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select . . .,
       (case when inv = 1 then sum(gross) over (partition by po_number) end) as gross,
       (case when inv = 1 then sum(line) over (partition by po_number) end) as line
from t
order by po_number, inv;
```

This is not an `order by` issue, because you have to move the data to the rows with the first invoice.